# multiple instances of tomcat versus virtual host

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

All servers in my project are running multiple instances of tomcat. I personally feel this setup would cause a JVM overhead. Is there any advantage of running multiple instances of tomcat over using virtual host feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all applications are stable there is no win in having multiple tomcats.

If not some pros (for multiple tomcats):

- You can kill the JVMs with OS-means, and hit only one application
- More security separation is possible, if each tomcat runs with a different account
- You can have different Tomcat-versions on the same server
- You can have different Java-versions for each Tomcat.

Some cons:

- You have to take care that the init-scripts (or services, if running on Win) do not influence each other
- You have to patch each Tomcat on its own
- You have to administer each Tomcat on its own
- Possible more memory overhead (depends on the OS)